# How to create a Nuxt 3 Plugin from Vue 3 Plugin? (vue3-markdown-it)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am new to Nuxt, and am attempting to turn the Vue plugin `vue3-markdown-it` into a Nuxt 3 plugin, but am receiving the following error:

`[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: Markdown If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.`

What am I doing incorrectly?

[Nuxt 3 Plugin Documentation](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/plugins/#vue-plugins)

```
// md-plugin.client.ts
import Markdown from 'vue3-markdown-it'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(Markdown)
})
```

```
// index.vue
<template>
    <main>
        <ClientOnly>
            <Markdown :source="content" />
        </ClientOnly>
    </main>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
    const { find } = useStrapi4()
    const {
        data: {
            attributes: { content },
        },
    } = await find('homepage')
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe give a read to this one: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/4924#discussioncomment-2750576

Comment: @kissu Thanks, thought that issue addresses a Vue3 component. I'm attempting to work with a plugin.

Comment: Both are the exact same problem IMO.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem on different plugin. I solved the problem by using component instead of plugin.

- Create a new file under the components folder (Markdown.vue).
- Add Markdown codes in this file:

  ```html
  <template>
    <Markdown :source="content" />
  </template>

  <script lang="ts" setup>
  import { defineProps } from "vue";
  import Markdown from 'vue3-markdown-it';

  defineProps({
    content: { type: any }
  });
  </script>
  ```

  *You can customize this code.*
- Delete plugin file (md-plugin.client.ts)

Now `<Markdown :source="content" />` will see our generated **Markdown** component. It worked me.

Comment: `import { defineProps } from "vue";` is not needed any more.